# Is it worse to bind one function to each object than one to all at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, append

I have loop and dynamically append links to `#content`. I wrote 2 ways.

(1)

```
$.each(array, function(key, value) {
    $('#content').append('<a href="#">text</a>');
    $('#content a:last').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({ url: ...
             ...
        });
    });
});
```

(2)

```
$.each(array, function(key, value) {
    $('#content').append('<a href="#">text</a>');
});

$('#content a').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({ url: ...
         ...
    });
});
```

**Q:**
Is it worse to use (1) way instead (2)? How do you know? How to set timers to test how many seconds every method goes (binding 'click' event)?

Comment: Why don't you see for yourself and run some tests at jsPerf.com?

Comment: In theory, doing it the first way avoids looping over them all twice, however that can still be reduced to one line rather than two, avoiding an additional call to queryselectorall.

Comment: I think `click` attaches event to all anchor tags under `#content`; you could use `on` to use delegation

Comment: You might as well run `$('#content').click( ... )` and check for `a` tag within the function to be even faster.

Comment: @Amberlamps I believe `on` already does that for you

Comment: @dm03514: Cool, I did not know that as I don´t use jQuery. But good to know, thanks!

Comment: How about delegating events, so you don't have to rebind them on each dynamically added link? `$('#content').on('click', 'a', function(e) { ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting timers is easy enough if you have a browser with a console, take a look at the implementation in Firefox (and probably Chrome too): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.time

Example:

```
console.time("append");
$.each(array, function(key, value) {
    $('#content').append('<a href="#">text</a>');
});
console.timeEnd("append");

console.time("click handler");

var myClickHandler = function(e) {
    $.ajax({ url: ...
         ...
    });
};

$('#content a').click(myClickHandler);
console.timeEnd("click handler");
```

My guess (and it is just that) is that the second is marginally faster, but the difference will almost certainly be negligible in perceivable terms. Note, I have removed the anonymous click handler and defined it as a single function to save multiple instances (which will give you a performance gain)

There are more obvious performance improvements you could make. For example, declaring $content as a variable instead of looking it up every time.

Comment: This only addresses how long it takes to attach the event handlers.  I'd think the big benefit of the second way comes from the reduction in total number of handlers attached to the DOM, when the click events actually occur.

Comment: This is true. At the very least, the click handler should be refactored in to a named function and passed by name instead of anonymously.

Comment: console.time("append"); works good! thank you. the (2) method is faster in 2-4 times

Answer (score 2):

i prefer and would recommend you to prefer the second one... it is cleaner, readable and does not create click handler again and again which is not required at all (for this reason delegated `on` was introduced in later version of jquery, to do the exact same thing with efficiency)....though i doubt your (2) script is working :).. since you have to delegate the click event to closest static parent for dynamically created elements which in your case is `a`..

```
$.each(array, function(key, value) {
  $('#content').append('<a href="#">text</a>');
});

$('#content').on('click','a',function(e) {
  $.ajax({ url: ...
     ...
  });
});
```

Comment: though I agree delegation is the preferred way here (+1), I think he meant: "create a bunch of elements, then bind the same handler to all of them" (no intention to delegate)

Comment: @JanDvorak .. hmmmmmm no comments.. :).. hope this helps .. :)

Comment: yes, helped :j i thought `.on('click')` and `.click` are the same funcs

Comment: @sirjay they are not. while `$el.click(func)` is just an alias for `$.el("click", func)`, `on` is much richer than that: it can do delegation, binding to arbitrary events and binding of multiple handlers with one call